# Efficient pairwise DTW calculation using numpy or cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython, joblib

I am trying to calculate the pairwise distances between multiple time-series contained in a numpy array. Please see the code below

```
print(type(sales))
print(sales.shape)

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(687, 157)
```

So, `sales` contains 687 time series of length 157. Using pdist to calculate the DTW distances between the time series.

```
import fastdtw
import scipy.spatial.distance as sd

def my_fastdtw(sales1, sales2):
    return fastdtw.fastdtw(sales1,sales2)[0]

distance_matrix = sd.pdist(sales, my_fastdtw)
```

**---EDIT: tried doing it without `pdist()`-----**

```
distance_matrix = []
m = len(sales)    
for i in range(0, m - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, m):
        distance_matrix.append(fastdtw.fastdtw(sales[i], sales[j]))
```

**---EDIT: parallelizing the inner for loop-----**

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing
import fastdtw

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1
N = 687

def my_fastdtw(sales1, sales2):
    return fastdtw.fastdtw(sales1,sales2)[0]

results = [[] for i in range(N)]
for i in range(0, N- 1):
    results[i] = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(my_fastdtw) (sales[i],sales[j])  for j in range(i + 1, N) )
```

All the methods are very slow. The parallel method takes around 12 minutes. Can someone please suggest an efficient way?

---EDIT: Following the steps mentioned in the answer below---

Here is how the lib folder looks like:

```
VirtualBox:~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastdtw-0.3.2-py3.6- linux-x86_64.egg/fastdtw$ ls
_fastdtw.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  fastdtw.py   __pycache__
_fastdtw.py                               __init__.py
```

So, there is a cython version of fastdtw in there. While installation, I did not receive any errors. Even now, when I pressed `CTRL-C` during my program execution, I can see that the pure python version is being used (`fastdtw.py`):

```
/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastdtw/fastdtw.py in fastdtw(x, y, radius, dist)

/home/vishal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastdtw/fastdtw.py in __fastdtw(x, y, radius, dist)
```

The code remains slow like before.

Comment: Read what `pdist` says about supplying your own function.  Note how many times it calls it.  What does `fastdtw` produce?  What are the items in `dm`?  I think `pdist` expects a simple number from the distance function.

Comment: @hpaulj, you are right, each call to `fastdtw` produces a `float` which is the distance needed by pdist, and it also returns a path. Please see my updated post.

Comment: It looks like `pdist` is the doing the same kind of iteration when given a Python function.  It's only faster when using one of its own compiled metrics.  Any speed improvement has to come from the `fastdtw` end.

Answer (score 11):

TL;DR

Your `fastdtw` falled to install the fast cpp-version and falls back silently to a pure-python version, which is slow.

You need to fix the installation of the `fastdtw`-package.

---

The whole calculation is done in `fastdtw`, so you cannot really speed it up from the outside. And parallelization and python is not such an easy thing (yet?).

The `fastdtw` documentation says it needs about `O(n)` operations for a comparison, so for your whole test-set it will need about order of magnitude of `10^9` operations, which should be finished in about some seconds, if programmed in, for example, C. The performance you see is nowhere near it.

If we look at the [code of `fastdtw`](https://github.com/slaypni/fastdtw) we see, that there are two versions: the cython/cpp-version which is fast and imported via cython and a slow fall back pure-python-version. If the fast version isn't preset, the slow python version is silently used.

So run your calculation, interrupt it with `Ctr+C` and you will see, that you are somewhere in python-code. You can also go to your lib-folder and see, that there is only the pure-python version inside.

So your installation of the fast `fastdtw`  version failed. Actually, I think the wheel-package is botched, at least for my version there is only the pure python code present.

What to do?

1. Get the source code, e.g. via `git clone https://github.com/slaypni/fastdtw`
2. go into `fstdtw` folder and run `python setup.py build`
3. watch out for errors. Mine was

> fatal error: numpy/npy_math.h: No such file or directory

4. fix it.

For me, the fix was to change the following lines in `setup.py`:

```
import numpy # THIS ADDED
extensions = [Extension(
        'fastdtw._fastdtw',
        [os.path.join('fastdtw', '_fastdtw' + ext)],
        language="c++",
        include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()], # AND ADDED numpy.get_include()
        libraries=["stdc++"]
    )]
```

5. repeat 3.+4. until successful
6. run `python setup.py install`

Now your program should be about 100 times faster.
`

Comment: @user1274878 the guys fixed the issue yesterday and with the current version (3.0.2) it works out of the box for me (I don't use anaconda)

Comment: @user1274878 it is hard to tell, what your problem could be and I cannot fix your setup remotely. Go to `.../fastdtw/__init__.py` and replace its code with `print("Loading fastdtw")
from ._fastdtw import fastdtw, dtw` into it. You should be able to see now, why the import of the fast version fails. If you don't see "Loading fastdtw" then you are using another version. Fix the problems you see.

Answer (score 8):

To be honest, `fastdtw` is not fast at all

```
from cdtw import pydtw
from dtaidistance import dtw
from fastdtw import fastdtw
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
s1=np.array([1,2,3,4],dtype=np.double)
s2=np.array([4,3,2,1],dtype=np.double)

%timeit dtw.distance_fast(s1, s2)
4.1 µs ± 28.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit d2 = pydtw.dtw(s1,s2,pydtw.Settings(step = 'p0sym', window = 'palival', param = 2.0, norm = False, compute_path = True)).get_dist()
45.6 µs ± 3.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit d3,_=fastdtw(s1, s2, dist=euclidean)
901 µs ± 9.95 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

`fastdtw` is 219 times slower than `dtaidistance` lib and 20x slower than `cdtw`

Consider changing. Here is `dtaidistance` git:

https://github.com/wannesm/dtaidistance

To install, just:

```
pip install dtaidistance
```

Comment: For larger time series (containing 3000 samples in my case) the situation looks a bit different: * dtw.distance(x,y): 21.120484339067534
* dtw.distance_fast(x,y): 0.35772456875758607
* fastdtw(x,y): 1.0159217517881522
* pydtw.dtw(x,y): 0.06623724053156366

Comment: very interesting results with pydtw.dtw...Did you use the same settings and did you run it multiple times? But, I imagine that for larger arrays, the average processing time will have a smaller proportional gap between them. @Hagbard

Comment: On my machine, different runs produce different results. My exact setup can be found [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52479046/different-results-and-performances-with-different-libraries).