# How to apply/implement Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) or Fast Dynamic Time Warping (FastDTW) in python between 3 or more signals?

Tags: python, signals, signal-processing, dtw

In time series analysis, dynamic time warping **(DTW)** is one of the algorithms for measuring similarity between two temporal sequences, which may vary in speed. Fast **DTW** is a more faster method. I would like to know how to implement this method not only between 2 signals but 3 or more.

```
distance, warp_path = fastdtw(series2, series1, dist=euclidean)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You essentially need to construct a matrix, evaluating the FastDTW algorithm on all possible combinations of the series.

```
import fastdtw
import scipy.spatial.distance as sd

def my_fastdtw(sales1, sales2):
    return fastdtw.fastdtw(sales1,sales2)[0]

distance_matrix = sd.pdist(sales, my_fastdtw)
```

You can see this thread for a reference on how to do it, as well as other possibilities: [Efficient pairwise DTW calculation using numpy or cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44994866/efficient-pairwise-dtw-calculation-using-numpy-or-cython)

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code based on @Julian'. If you want to calculate the `dtw` of several columns in the data frame `df` and one target column, you can use the following code:

```
import fastdtw

def cal_fastdtw(series1, series2):
    return fastdtw.fastdtw(series1, series2)[0]

df.apply(lambda x: cal_fastdtw(df['target'].values, x.values) if x.name != 'target' else None)
```