# How do you align multiple time series (not just 2) in python using DTW - Dynamic Time Warping?

Tags: python, time-series, dtw

I found these two articles discussing aligning multiple 'n' number of time series using dynamic time warping or DTW.

[How to apply/implement Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) or Fast Dynamic Time Warping (FastDTW) in python between 3 or more signals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65970138/how-to-apply-implement-dynamic-time-warping-dtw-or-fast-dynamic-time-warping)
[Efficient pairwise DTW calculation using numpy or cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44994866/efficient-pairwise-dtw-calculation-using-numpy-or-cython)

However, they fail to describe all the steps involved to find a minimally distant path for all 'n' number of time series.

In one of the answers from the above links, it states to calculate a distance matrix of all pair-wise paths. But then, fails to mention what to do with the distance matrix in order to create a plot with 'n' number of time series that are all optimally aligned.

How would you take the distance matrix (pair-wise distances between 'n' number of time series) & align all 'n' number of time-series?

Or, is there a different approach to aligning all 'n' number of time series?

Comment: Did you ever find anything else on this?

Comment: I have tried using the tslearn library to create a barycenter average of all the trajectories. Then, I loop through all the trajectories and create a 'best match' for each to the barycenter. The pairs then are a DTW match between the original trajectory to the barycenter average. Finally, I rescaled all the trajectories to the longest trajectory match.